# Facebook Login in two different apps of one iPhone

Tags: iphone

I developed two apps with facebook integration  in both the Apps ,  my requirement is if i opend one app and login to facebook account , and if i open  second app it should login at the same time .

Thanks 
nikhil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible, since both apps would then have to use the same Facebook App ID.

And since the Facebook App ID is should be part of the App URL scheme, iOS can't see the difference between the two apps and will open the one installed last.

You can try an store the Facebook login data in the keychain and use that in the other app, but not sure if that will work.